# Changing the output type of a Windows Service project

Tags: windows, windows-services

A project I'm writing at the moment requires a Windows Service to be written as it needs to run unattended. One requirement in the specification says that the service should also be able to be run interactively. This is no great problem as I can simply use Reflection to get at the `OnStart/OnStop` methods and use `Console.ReadKey()` to pause for keyboard input.

[image]

All that's really causing me to pause here is that in order to do this I need to change the output type of the project from Windows Application to Console Application. I'd like someone that has a detailed understanding of the differences between these two choices to explain what the difference is between them and if there are any ramifications for stability in production.

Comment: The only difference is a field in the PE header that designates the subsystem (Windows or Console). When the OS launches an executable that runs in the Console subsystem, it allocates a console. If the application runs in the Windows subsystem, the OS will not allocate a console. That's as far as the system is concerned. I'm not familiar with .NET so I cannot comment on (potential) ramifications with respect to .NET's application model.

Comment: Irrespective of the subsystem, any PE file can export the functions required by the SCM to control and communicate with the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, while executing in interactive mode, the service is NOT showing Forms, you can change the output type and expect no trouble. If Forms are needed, output type should remain Windows Application. As a general rule, I always start developing service apps as Console apps. It's easy to debug. When it is almost done with testing and debugging, I change to a service app.

Comment: There are a lot of code examples, [this was useful to me](https://alastaircrabtree.com/how-to-run-a-dotnet-windows-service-as-a-console-app/)

Comment: That's a much simpler approach than mine! Thanks for the link...

Comment: @aamartin2k - when you say "service app", you don't mean the Output Type in the project properties, right?